# Emacs org-mode publishing Agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do you publish the agenda for org mode?  I am currently using htmlize to write just the agenda buffer, but I want it to publish all the related buffers, and link the agenda items to the corresponding locations in the other files.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Wow, I'd like an answer to this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a built-in way to do this, so I ended up programming my own.  You can find the function org-publish-agenda at http://nflath.com/2009/10/org-mode/.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to supply a file extension when writing the agenda view.

`C-x C-w` to save the agenda. When it asks you for the location, you just enter a filename that ends with `.html`

For example, I saved my agenda in `/tmp/agenda.html`

If you want to save it as plain-text, you just give it a `.txt` extension.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question, because with blorgit, for example, this facility will be great.
Eureka! OrgMobile creates *.org files for different agenda-views.