# Org-mode Agenda export to html with C-x C-w has broken http links

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've searched "org-mode agenda html" and looked carefully at

- [Use orgmode agenda content in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395131/use-orgmode-agenda-content-in-html)
- [Emacs org-mode publishing Agenda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563621/emacs-org-mode-publishing-agenda/1592490#1592490)

with no insight. I've recently installed emacs 24.5 on two different OS X Mavericks machines, once with Mac Ports, once from the tarball. I didn't see html as an option when using C-c C-e in org-mode, so i ran find across the machine installed with tarball and couldn't find htmlize.el. I fetched version 1.43 and put it in my load path: html now appears in C-c C-e. (This loadpath is mirrored between the two machines.)

Now when i run C-x C-w at the agenda view, i have a satisfactory html export with the exception of links. They URL includes the close bracket, open bracket and first word of the link text.  `<a href="https://oclc.webex.com/oclc/j.php?blahblahblah][Webex">Webex</a>` Note that the engine is able to figure out the end of the URL because the second word in the link text in the org document becomes its own second link, well formed: `<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/blahblah/edit][Engineering">Engineering</a><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/blahblah/edit"> Doc</a>`

This annoying behavior occurs on both machines.

Experiments on the macports machine result in the following.  An export of an org file to html via C-c C-e produces well formed links; an export of the agenda via M-x org-export-dispatch produces well formed links, but all the content is in one paragraph tag and all the lines run together.

ETA source 
'** 10:00 Team checkin - [[https://oclc.webex.com/oclc/j.php?MTID%blah][Webex]] - [[https://docs.google.com/document/d/blah_blah-blah/edit][Engineering Doc]]'

I forget where i picked up the version 1.43 htmlize.el. Is that a version working well for others exporting agendas with URL links?

Ideas?

Better place to reach the org-mode community? (I have to say that stackoverflow Q&A have been helpful as i've gotten started with org mode. Thank you!)

Comment: Can you show your raw markup in the `.org` file - turn off font-lock or use "Org > Hyperlinks > Literal links" to view them.  If the url contains special characters, you may have to use `@@html` forms.

Comment: I added source to the body of the message. The URL has %, -, _ -- which shouldn't be special!

Comment: I have downloaded version 1.47 of `htmlize.el` from the package archive melpa, and it still has this incorrect behaviour.  I suggest you write to the author.  Alternative places to ask are the mailing list https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode and http://emacs.stackexchange.com or

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and help @AndrewSwann!